# Custom return type of a function in Oracle PL SQl

Tags: oracle, functions, plsql

I have a query and I want to wrap it into a function. Currently query returns `in_count`, `in_sum`, `out_count`, `out_sum`. I only know how to return a "primitive type". So currently I have four different functions with `select in_count from /* query 3*/`, `select in_sum from /* query 3*/`, etc. Even though query 3 returns all necessary fields.  That I combine in one statement. This is redundant and I should be able to return `in_count`, `in_sum`, `out_count`, `out_sum` from a single function.

I have a query that returns nearby segments count and weight for a given hardcoded segment (see query 3). I want to make a function
f(id) that executes query 3 for id from the argument. So far I was able to create four functions, each returning A FIELD (see query 1).
Query 2 can then call these our functions to get a table containing rows of stats for each segment ID.
I don't like several things in this solution:
(a) I execute essentially the same code four times to return four numbers. I wish I can execute code once and return a tuple (int, int, int, int).
(b) Any discussion on user defined functions starts with "pointers are bad". Here I seem to use pointers.
Question: What is the right way to create a table produced by query 2? I suspect Oracle allows to return type row(int,int,int,int), but what would be the syntax?
Where can I find examples of user defined functions? Oracle docs only show how to return number or binary integer (what is that?) in their docs.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm#i2153260

```
  --(Query 1)  creates a function
CREATE OR REPLACE Function dummy_function   ( name_in IN number )
   RETURN number
IS
   cnumber number;
   cursor c1 is
       select rt.in_count from (   --also do rt.in_sum, rt.out_count, rt.out_sum as three additional functions
     --COMPLEX_QUERY
  ) rt ;
BEGIN
   open c1;
   fetch c1 into cnumber;
   if c1%notfound then
      cnumber := 0;
   end if;
   close c1;
RETURN cnumber;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END;

-- (Query 2)
SELECT id, dummy_function(t.id) AS func_in , dummy_function1(t.id) AS func_in_sum, dummy_function2(t.id) AS func_out, dummy_function3(t.id) AS func_out_sum , t.* FROM dummy_links t;

-- (Query 3)   -- COMPLEX_QUERY:  -- note  START WITH ID = name_in: here name_in is an argument (id=in range 1..10 works)
     WITH
dummy_links as (
SELECT 1 ID, 'A' in_node, 'B' out_node, 17 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 2 ID, 'B' in_node, 'A' out_node, 4 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 3 ID, 'C' in_node, 'A' out_node, 5 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 4 ID, 'A' in_node, 'D' out_node, 6 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 5 ID, 'C' in_node, 'G' out_node, 33 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 6 ID, 'X' in_node, 'Z' out_node, 12 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 7 ID, 'Z' in_node, 'Y' out_node, 15 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 8 ID, 'X' in_node, 'Y' out_node, 42 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 9 ID, 'K' in_node, 'M' out_node, 66 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 10 ID, 'A' in_node, 'Z' out_node, 20 weight FROM dual),
     res AS (SELECT ID,
            in_node,
            out_node,
            weight,
            MAX(CASE WHEN ID = connect_by_root(ID) THEN in_node END) OVER () orig_in_node,
            MAX(CASE WHEN ID = connect_by_root(ID) THEN out_node END) OVER () orig_out_node,
            MAX(CASE WHEN ID = connect_by_root(ID) THEN ID END) OVER () orig_id,
            CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN ID = connect_by_root(ID) THEN in_node END) OVER () IN (in_node, out_node) THEN 'in'
               ELSE 'out'
            END direction_from_orig_node,
            LEAST(in_node, out_node) node1,
            GREATEST(in_node, out_node) node2,
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY LEAST(in_node, out_node), GREATEST(in_node, out_node) ORDER BY weight) rn
         FROM   dummy_links
         START WITH ID = name_in
         CONNECT BY NOCYCLE (PRIOR out_node IN (in_node, out_node)
                  OR PRIOR in_node IN (in_node, out_node))
                  AND LEVEL <= 2)
  SELECT orig_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN direction_from_orig_node = 'in' THEN node1||'~'||node2 END) in_count,
       nvl(SUM(CASE WHEN direction_from_orig_node = 'in' THEN weight END), 0) in_sum,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN direction_from_orig_node = 'out' THEN node1||'~'||node2 END) out_count,
       nvl(SUM(CASE WHEN direction_from_orig_node = 'out' THEN weight END), 0) out_sum
  FROM   res
  WHERE  rn = 1
  AND    ID != orig_id
  GROUP BY orig_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a function that returns ref cursor? I've used your `QUERY 3` without any changes (line 7 onwards), encapsulated it into *ref cursor* function stuff. Have a look.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_rc (name_in in number)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open l_rc for
  7    WITH
  8       dummy_links as (
  9             SELECT 1 ID, 'A' in_node, 'B' out_node, 17 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
 10             SELECT 2 ID, 'B' in_node, 'A' out_node, 4 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
 11             SELECT 3 ID, 'C' in_node, 'A' out_node, 5 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
 12             SELECT 4 ID, 'A' in_node, 'D' out_node, 6 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
 13             SELECT 5 ID, 'C' in_node, 'G' out_node, 33 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
 14             SELECT 6 ID, 'X' in_node, 'Z' out_node, 12 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
 15             SELECT 7 ID, 'Z' in_node, 'Y' out_node, 15 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
 16             SELECT 8 ID, 'X' in_node, 'Y' out_node, 42 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
 17             SELECT 9 ID, 'K' in_node, 'M' out_node, 66 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
 18             SELECT 10 ID, 'A' in_node, 'Z' out_node, 20 weight FROM dual),
 19       res AS (SELECT ID,
 20              in_node,
 21              out_node,
 22              weight,
 23              MAX(CASE WHEN ID = connect_by_root(ID) THEN in_node END) OVER () orig_in_node,
 24              MAX(CASE WHEN ID = connect_by_root(ID) THEN out_node END) OVER () orig_out_node,
 25              MAX(CASE WHEN ID = connect_by_root(ID) THEN ID END) OVER () orig_id,
 26              CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN ID = connect_by_root(ID) THEN in_node END) OVER () IN (in_node, out_node) THEN 'in'
 27                 ELSE 'out'
 28              END direction_from_orig_node,
 29              LEAST(in_node, out_node) node1,
 30              GREATEST(in_node, out_node) node2,
 31              row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY LEAST(in_node, out_node), GREATEST(in_node, out_node) ORDER BY weight) rn
 32           FROM   dummy_links
 33           START WITH ID = name_in
 34           CONNECT BY NOCYCLE (PRIOR out_node IN (in_node, out_node)
 35                    OR PRIOR in_node IN (in_node, out_node))
 36                    AND LEVEL <= 2)
 37    SELECT orig_id,
 38         COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN direction_from_orig_node = 'in' THEN node1||'~'||node2 END) in_count,
 39         nvl(SUM(CASE WHEN direction_from_orig_node = 'in' THEN weight END), 0) in_sum,
 40         COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN direction_from_orig_node = 'out' THEN node1||'~'||node2 END) out_count,
 41         nvl(SUM(CASE WHEN direction_from_orig_node = 'out' THEN weight END), 0) out_sum
 42    FROM   res
 43    WHERE  rn = 1
 44    AND    ID != orig_id
 45    GROUP BY orig_id;
 46
 47    return l_rc;
 48  end f_rc;
 49  /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL>   select f_rc(1) from dual;

F_RC(1)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

   ORIG_ID   IN_COUNT     IN_SUM  OUT_COUNT    OUT_SUM
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          4         35          0          0


SQL>
```

Comment: thank you!. Can you look at this question too/ Getting values from the cursor is the last missing piece of info for me.

Comment: Please look at this follow up question. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222469/extract-values-from-oracle-pl-sql-cursor

Comment: You're welcome; I posted an answer in the follow up question; have a look, please.