# Extract values from oracle pl sql cursor

Tags: oracle-12c, plsql

I have a function that returns a cursor. When I execute

```
select t.id, t.f_rc(id) from my_table t
```

I get

id F_RC(TID)
1   < cursor >
2   < cursor >
3   < cursor >
...

How to expand values to get content of cursor? Would cursor be an array I would just do

```
select t.id, t.f_rc(id)[1], t.f_rc(id)[2], t.f_rc(id)[3], t.f_rc(id)[4] from my_table t
```

But this doesn't work with PL SQL.

```
create or replace function f_rc (name_in in number)
    return sys_refcursor
  is
    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  begin
    open l_rc for
    WITH
       dummy_links as (
             SELECT 1 ID, 'A' in_node, 'B' out_node, 17 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 2 ID, 'B' in_node, 'A' out_node, 4 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 3 ID, 'C' in_node, 'A' out_node, 5 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 4 ID, 'A' in_node, 'D' out_node, 6 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 5 ID, 'C' in_node, 'G' out_node, 33 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 6 ID, 'X' in_node, 'Z' out_node, 12 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 7 ID, 'Z' in_node, 'Y' out_node, 15 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 8 ID, 'X' in_node, 'Y' out_node, 42 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 9 ID, 'K' in_node, 'M' out_node, 66 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 10 ID, 'A' in_node, 'Z' out_node, 20 weight FROM dual),
       res AS (SELECT ID,
              in_node,
              out_node,
              weight,
              MAX(CASE WHEN ID = connect_by_root(ID) THEN in_node END) OVER () orig_in_node,
              MAX(CASE WHEN ID = connect_by_root(ID) THEN out_node END) OVER () orig_out_node,
              MAX(CASE WHEN ID = connect_by_root(ID) THEN ID END) OVER () orig_id,
              CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN ID = connect_by_root(ID) THEN in_node END) OVER () IN (in_node, out_node) THEN 'in'
                 ELSE 'out'
              END direction_from_orig_node,
              LEAST(in_node, out_node) node1,
              GREATEST(in_node, out_node) node2,
              row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY LEAST(in_node, out_node), GREATEST(in_node, out_node) ORDER BY weight) rn
           FROM   dummy_links
           START WITH ID = name_in
           CONNECT BY NOCYCLE (PRIOR out_node IN (in_node, out_node)
                    OR PRIOR in_node IN (in_node, out_node))
                    AND LEVEL <= 2)
    SELECT orig_id,
         COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN direction_from_orig_node = 'in' THEN node1||'~'||node2 END) in_count,
         nvl(SUM(CASE WHEN direction_from_orig_node = 'in' THEN weight END), 0) in_sum,
         COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN direction_from_orig_node = 'out' THEN node1||'~'||node2 END) out_count,
         nvl(SUM(CASE WHEN direction_from_orig_node = 'out' THEN weight END), 0) out_sum
    FROM   res
    WHERE  rn = 1
    AND    ID != orig_id
    GROUP BY orig_id;

    return l_rc;
  end f_rc;


  with        dummy_t as (
             SELECT 1 ID, 'A' in_node, 'B' out_node, 17 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 2 ID, 'B' in_node, 'A' out_node, 4 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 3 ID, 'C' in_node, 'A' out_node, 5 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 4 ID, 'A' in_node, 'D' out_node, 6 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 5 ID, 'C' in_node, 'G' out_node, 33 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 6 ID, 'X' in_node, 'Z' out_node, 12 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 7 ID, 'Z' in_node, 'Y' out_node, 15 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 8 ID, 'X' in_node, 'Y' out_node, 42 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 9 ID, 'K' in_node, 'M' out_node, 66 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 10 ID, 'A' in_node, 'Z' out_node, 20 weight FROM dual)


select dl.id, f_rc(dl.id) from dummy_t dl ;
```

---

This works as expected:

```
 -- ..dummy_t definition s above..
 select  dt.id as d2id, ct.my_dlid, ct.my_cur from 
         (select cur_t.id as my_dlid, f_rc(cur_t.id) as my_cur from dummy_t cur_t ) ct,
         dummy_t dt
         --where ct.my_dlid = dt.id --this works returning 1 1 < cursor> 
         where ct.my_cur[1] = dt.id --this fails
```

What is the correct way to access values inside of a cursor? in a query? Or should I just save values to a temporary table?

Answer (score 0):

It looks OK (as far as ref cursor is concerned) to me - if you run it in SQL*Plus.

```
<snip>
 11               SELECT 10 ID, 'A' in_node, 'Z' out_node, 20 weight FROM dual)
 12  select dl.id, f_rc(dl.id) from dummy_t dl ;

        ID F_RC(DL.ID)
---------- --------------------
         1 CURSOR STATEMENT : 2

CURSOR STATEMENT : 2

   ORIG_ID   IN_COUNT     IN_SUM  OUT_COUNT    OUT_SUM
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          4         35          0          0

         2 CURSOR STATEMENT : 2

CURSOR STATEMENT : 2

   ORIG_ID   IN_COUNT     IN_SUM  OUT_COUNT    OUT_SUM
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2          0          0          3         31

         3 CURSOR STATEMENT : 2

CURSOR STATEMENT : 2

   ORIG_ID   IN_COUNT     IN_SUM  OUT_COUNT    OUT_SUM
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         3          1         33          3         30
```

Which tool do you use? If it is some GUI (such as TOAD or SQL Developer), you'll have to find a way to display data in a *readable* manner.

For example - **TOAD**: as far as I can tell, you should rewrite a query you posted into a procedure:

```
create or replace procedure p_rc (par_rc out sys_refcursor) as
begin  
  open par_rc for select f_rc(dl.id) 
  from 
    (        SELECT 1 ID, 'A' in_node, 'B' out_node, 17 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 2 ID, 'B' in_node, 'A' out_node, 4 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 3 ID, 'C' in_node, 'A' out_node, 5 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 4 ID, 'A' in_node, 'D' out_node, 6 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 5 ID, 'C' in_node, 'G' out_node, 33 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 6 ID, 'X' in_node, 'Z' out_node, 12 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 7 ID, 'Z' in_node, 'Y' out_node, 15 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 8 ID, 'X' in_node, 'Y' out_node, 42 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 9 ID, 'K' in_node, 'M' out_node, 66 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT 10 ID, 'A' in_node, 'Z' out_node, 20 weight FROM dual
    ) dl;
end;
/
```

Once it is created,

- find it in Object Browser,
- right-click its name,
- choose "Execute procedure" from the pop-up menu
- click the "Reset current procedure parameters to default values" (looks like a "Refresh" button)
- click OK

The result will be displayed in a new, "REF CURSOR Results" window and look like this:

```
1, 4, 35, 0, 0
2, 0, 0, 3, 31    
3, 1, 33, 3, 30
<snip>
```

Comment: I am using PL/SQL Developer OCI: version 11.1 Oracle DB 12c Enterprise. I run `create or replace procedure/function` in a new query window. I am looking for a return type that I can join or query against. `select t.id, f1(t.id) as my_var, f2(t.value) as my_val from my_table t` should return a table that I can further slice and dice as if it was `select my_id, my_var, my_val from my_t`

Comment: I've updated the question. Briefly, given a table `select my_id, my_cur from cur_t` such that `my_cur` is a `< cursor >` I want to do  `select my_id, my_cur from cur_t where my_cur.id = 42`. Is this possible?